# How do I compare one index to the previous index within the same list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make this program look at each previous number in a list, and determine if that number is bigger than it. If it is, it should record how many times bigger, and return it at the end. i.e. the count (I'm using num as the variable) starts at 0. But 10 is bigger than 7 so num becomes 1. Now 7 isn't bigger than 20 so the count stays the same. but 20 is bigger than 15 so the count (num) is 2. and 15 is bigger than 4 (count is 3). Now 4 is not bigger than 6 (count does not change) and 6 is not bigger than the next number because there is no next number. This is what I have now. I'm thinking lst[i] and lst[i+1] need to be used to reference index maybe? Can anyone walk me through this? Thanks.

```
def count(lst):
num = 0 
some sort of division here? then add to num variable?

#main prog
( count([10, 7, 20, 15, 4, 6]) )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
def count(lst):
    return sum(np.diff(lst)>0)
```

`diff` gives the difference between successive elements, the sum returns the number of positive differences.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count(lst):
    return sum(i > j for i,j in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]))
```

Here we zip together the list, offset by one, to get the consecutive pairs.  Then we compare each pair.  Booleans are integers, so we can sum them to produce the final count.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def count(lst):
    answer = 0
    for i,num in enumerate(lst[1:], 1):
        answer += num < lst[i-1]
    return answer
```

It turns out that adding boolean values to integers forces the `bool`s to be treated as `int`s as well (`True` is `1` and `False` is `0`). So you can use that to make more readable code.

Hope this helps

Comment: It should be returning a 3. This returns 2

Comment: @user1487497: Oh I see the problem. I quickly scanned your question, which is why I missed something. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

From the itertools recipes:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def count(lst):
    return sum(a>b for a,b in pairwise(lst))
```

then

```
count([10, 7, 20, 15, 4, 6])  # => 3
```

Comment: I looked at this and first questioned why is `a,b = tee(iterable)` preferable to `a,b = iter(iterable),iter(iterable)`? Then it occurred to me that if iterable is a generator, then you don't really get a chance to make two iterators on it. But tee will create a virtual second iterator without actually iterating twice.